# How to execute sql scripts in Pentaho with postgresql database?

Tags: pentaho

Im using Pentaho for my ETL tool project. Can I have a detailed step by step on how to for the ff.

1. I want to have a repository for all the sql scripts we are running everyday.
2. I want to learn how to schedule this routine.

Daily we ran different queries in postgres database and we want it to automate. Can you help me this. I would appreciate your immediate response. Thank you.

tin,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a step back and reading [the manual](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Spoon+User+Guide) at this point. If you're serious about this, later on you'll be happy you have read it. Once you feel comfortable with the tool, you might want to read this [excellent book](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470635177.html) as well. Do that and all your questions will be answered, promised. You can also drop by the unofficial IRC channel. There are always fine folks from the community and some core developers available to help you. It's channel ##pentaho on irc.freenode.net.

There are no quick way to properly use these tools. They are powerful and will help you do a lot, but they are complex and you will have to figure out how to use them to your advantage and that requires experience. Trust me, I work at Pentaho. =)

Comment: Hi Luc,

Thank you for this. I really appreciate your kindness. Do you know whom I can chat online? Thanks!